# Where and what is built in C# Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net

After successfully following this [introduction to Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) (although unable to "run" by pressing f5) I am really confused as to what is built and what is run when you create a WebAPI2 project.  The only way I was able to test if it was working was by right clicking the project and clicking View -> View in Browser. I can't seem to find any .exe in the build folder (the app does build fine) to run.

What exactly is built and what is required to run a WebAPI2 projecT?

Comment: What happens when you try to run the application via F5? When you created the application, did you create it as a console application like the tutorial says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only output in a web project are a bunch of DLL's and maybe some static files that you could be using in your project (see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx) about ASP.NET Web Project Folder Structure) . You don't have a .exe or an executable file in this case. Your built app requires a web server in order to execute, and when you are developing a project you have some options. Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(v=vs.120).aspx) about Web Servers in Visual Studio.

In order to run your project pressing F5, check if your ASP.NET Web Api project is configured as startup project. Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx) about how to configure it.

If you are still having any issue trying to run your web application in Visual Studio, please provide us with more information about your problem or errors, so we can provide you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks. How then is a Web API2 app deployed? I was under the impression that it was a self-hosted app. Ie some .exe or service running in the background providing a web based service.

Comment: @user3822370 - self hosting is an option, but you would have to set that up. This might be a helpful resource: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Comment: That's what I don't understand. I've gone through that tutorial, but it creates a console application, and doesn't seem accessible by a browser

Comment: @user3822370 I'm not familiar with doing self hosting with Web API, but the demo seems to imply that when the self hosted exe is running, you can make an HTTP GET request to `http://localhost:9000/api/values` to see the output.

Comment: @mason you would think so, but unfortunately this doesn't work

Comment: @user3822370 I do not know what you mean by "does not work". You need to more clearly explain your situation.

Comment: Simply put `This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. By contrast, the WebAPI tutorial worked quite easily.

Comment: What do you mean the tutorial worked easily. Isn't that what you're doing? Please edit your question to include more detail about what steps you've taken.